# How to put every two buttons on one rows with border separate between each row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular8, text-align

I work on `angular 8` I need to make web page design using
html and css or bootstrap

my issue i face how to put every two `buttons` beside

each other with border and after finish first row

go to new row with new buttons .

[image: buttons with arrange]

what i try

```
<input 
    hidden 
    type="file" 
/>

<button >
    Upload
</button>

<div style="width:400px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 130px"> 
        <button
    color="primary">
    Download Template
</button>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 225px"> 
        <button
    color="primary">
    Export
</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each row into two columns using `display: flex` on the row and `width 50%` on the row children.

Then you can apply a border to the row.

```css
.row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.row:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.row div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="file"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><button>Button Name</button></div>
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><button>Button Long Name</button></div>
  <div><button>Button</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i need remaining how to add upload button on first row

Comment: so how to add upload button on first row

Comment: I've added it 